# Can I rotate a DataVisualization.Charting.Chart 90° counter-clockwise?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mschart

I need to plot histograms of a laser beam profile in both the horizontal and vertical directions.

The horizontal histogram is plotted normally, with Y vs X.

I am near a solution when plotting the vertical histogram with X vs Y. However, since I am  using a `SeriesChartType.Area` style chart, the area is filled from top to bottom instead of right to left. (note the vertical histogram does not line up with the image for the moment, and this is a clockwise rotation)

[image: Beam and histograms]

Code to plot:

```vb
Dim series As Series

Me.chtHorizontal.Series.Clear()
series = New Series("Horizontal")
series.Points.DataBindXY(
    dictionaryOfHistogramHorizontal.Keys,
    String.Empty,
    dictionaryOfHistogramHorizontal.Values,
    String.Empty)
Me.chtHorizontal.Series.Add(series)

Me.chtVertical.Series.Clear()
series = New Series("Vertical")
series.Points.DataBindXY(
    dictionaryOfHistogramVertical.Values,
    String.Empty,
    dictionaryOfHistogramVertical.Keys,
    String.Empty)
    Me.chtVertical.Series.Add(series)
Me.chtVertical.Series.Add(series)
```

I have looked for a property of the ChartArea which would allow me to rotate ccw, but could not find one. This would be ideal because everything would be rotated globally. Instead I have swapped X and Y because it got me closer to a solution.

I have also looked for a property of the series which would allow me to fill right to left instead of the default top to bottom, but could not find one.

I would like the chart to be filled (`SeriesChartType.Area`), but if I didn't, I could just use a line chart. This is not the solution I am looking for.